# Find $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {(\log(n))^x}{n^y}$ with $x,y \in \Bbb{R}+$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {(\log(n))^x}{n^y} \text{ with } x,y \in \Bbb{R}+$$

Hey i tried the following.
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {(\log(n))^x}{n^y}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {e^{\log(\log(n))x}}{e^{\log(n)y}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{\log(\log(n))x-\log(n)y} $$

I feel like this doesnt help me much. Can i please get a hint on how to continue ?

I tried Lhopital also but i dont think it would help me because $x,y$ can be numbers with comma.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there. You just need to show that $x \log \log n - y \log n = \left( x \frac{\log \log n}{\log n} - y \right) \log n \to - \infty$.

It suffices to show that $\frac{\log \log n}{\log n} \to 0$. If you apply L'hopital's rule here, you get $\frac{\frac{1}{n\log n}}{\frac{1}{n}} = \frac{1}{\log n} \to 0$. So, you have $\left( x \frac{\log \log n}{\log n} - y \right) \log n$ behaving like $-y \log n$, which tends to $-\infty$. So, you have the limit being $e^{-\infty} = 0$

Comment: why does it suffice to show that $loglogn /logn $ goes to 0 ?

Comment: Then $x \frac{\log \log n}{\log n} -y \to -y$, and you use limit of product is product of limits (when both exist).

Comment: o i got it thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

One can use derivative of the function $\varphi(x)=(\log x)/x^{\alpha}$ to show that for large $x$, one has $\log x\leq C_{\alpha}x^{\alpha}$, here $\alpha>0$. Return to your question, if we put $\alpha=y/(2x)$, then $(\log n)^{x}\leq C_{\alpha}n^{y/2}$ for large $n$, then $(\log n)^{x}/n^{y}\leq\dfrac{C_{\alpha}}{n^{y/2}}$, now taking $n\rightarrow\infty$ and use Squeeze Theorem to show the limit is zero.